# How to enable rich:orderingList buttons

Tags: jquery, richfaces

How to enable [rich:orderingList](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_orderingList.html) buttons by default

EDIT:

The First, Up, Down, Last buttons are not enabled unless an item is selected within the orderingList. But I would like to preferably mimic selecting the first element in the orderingList and enable these buttons on page load. How should I do this?

Table 6.222 on the following link shows that enable is not yet implemented.

```
hide()  Hides ordering control (to be implemented)
show()  Shows ordering control (to be implemented)
isShown()   Checks if current control is shown (to be implemented)
enable()    Enables ordering control (to be implemented)
disable()   Disables ordering control (to be implemented)
isEnabled() Checks if current control is enabled (to be implemented)
```

We are willing to look at any solution or workaround which is possible using JQuery or Richfaces 3.3.x to get this functionality.